# Rails 5 test errors from find params[:id] in before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, best-in-place

I'm writing an app in Rails 5 with the gem 'best-in-place' being used for the update action view. Even though the app works fine and updates the right parameters of the right offer, the test suite throws up this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Offer with 'id'=
app/controllers/offers_controller.rb:71:in `correct_user'
```

Here is the offending code. It is a before filter for the update action:

```
70: def correct_user
71:     @offer = Offer.find params[:id]
72:     @user = @offer.user
73:     redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
```

but the PUT clearly has the id paramater defined as id = '109':

```
Started PUT "/offers/109" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-11 17:21:33 -0400
Processing by OffersController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"offer"=>{"category"=>"d"},     "authenticity_token"=>"9Y94wYzCrCvyygNk5GJXRe488JPd51YCSWQLe6Lpo3MgglfK1SrI1NcEj334T9HaAkAazlS212i4FZ+akDyelg==", "id"=>"109"}
```

This is the offer fixture I use in the test:

```
one:
   category: MyText
   plan_name: MyString
   price: $109
   rate: Month
   plan_customer_satisfaction: 1
   user_id: users(:michael).id
```

And the user fixture:

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  username: mexample
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: Time.zone.now
```

This is the test:

```
def setup
   @user = users(:michael)
   @offer = offers(:one)
end

test "should update when logged in" do
   log_in_as(@user)
   patch offers_update_path(@offer), params: { offer: { category: 'Heating',
                                           plan_name: 'Synergy',
                                           price: '$120',
                                           rate: 'Month' } }
   assert_response :success
end
```

If you need more information, please let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you are saying that you clearly have a record in test db before calling action but when `correct_user` gets called there is nothing? You check it right?

Comment: yup, record is fine.

Comment: Can you show us a test?

Comment: I updated the question with the test and fixtures used in the test. Let me know if I should post anything else.

Comment: Have you tried to create offer record directly via ActiveRecord?  `@offer = Offer.create!(...)` Also you can put in before action call just to make sure